# List all projects in Google Compute Engine using gcloud

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcutil, gcloud

Is it possible to use gcloud or gcutil to list all registered projects for a login? At https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/gcloud there is no mention of such an option.

Similar to `gcloud config list --all`, I am looking for something like `gcloud project list --all`

Answer (score 36):

`gcloud` has a component that lets you [list your gcloud projects](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/list):

```
gcloud projects list
```

Comment: the preview component doesn't come installed by default, add it by typing `gcloud components update preview`

Comment: @kzahel is right that this component doesn't come installed by default. At present you dont need to run any extra command - gcloud automatically detects missing component when gcloud alpha command is triggered & asks you if you want to install it.

Comment: This is no long in beta, so you can just run `gcloud projects list`

Answer (score 5):

The tools can get a specific project, but in order to list all your projects you have to go to https://cloud.google.com/console